# BASH, .sh файлы. Как уложить несколько команд в файл?

Tags: bash, sh

Например:

```
RUN  

$php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

И следующая команда

```
$php composer-setup.php
```

Какой разделитье должен быть между командами?
Я пробовал символ `&` и символ `\`. Но не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие правила разделения для команд?

Спасибо!

Comment: & отправляет команду в фон.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Памятка:

```
A &     # выполнить А в фоне
A; B    # выполнить А, потом В, независимо от результата А
A && B  # выполнить В только если выполнение А было успешным
A || B  # выполнить В только если выполнение А завершилось ошибкой
```

Answer (score 1):

Команды в bash разделяются переносом строки, то есть просто каждая новая команда в новой строке

Comment: Необязательно. Синтаксис у него довольно сложный. И вообще, shell -- (если мы о программировании на нём) совсем не для новичков.

Comment: @0andriy Я уже понял) Я сказал основываясь на том, что видел в скриптах и ошибся)